# What are the utterance for "action.devices.commands.appInstall, action.devices.commands.appSearch" command?

Tags: google-smart-home, fulfillment

I am developing Google smart home I would like to execute the
"action.devices.commands.appInstall or action.devices.commands.appSearch" but I am unable to figure out utterance for these commands.

Ex - with the utterance "Launch Yotube on My TV" google assistant invokes "action.devices.commands.appSelect" action.

Few sample utterances which I have tried. But it's not working:

Look for Yotube on the My TV

Install Yotube app by key  on the My TV

search for Yotube on the My TV

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the following [document](https://developers.google.com/assistant/smarthome/traits/appselector#device-commands) to get an idea as how to work with utterances for appSelect, appSearch and appInstall. For example, to work with appSearch you can use either one of the two utterances:

- Search for [AppKey] app by key
- Search for [AppName] app by name